# Uploading donations from a spreadsheet

Tags: donations, upload

In another CRM program I was able to upload several donations at once into the system (from a spreadsheet). Can I do this in CiviCRM? the program would look for matches of names and update those contacts, then would create new records for ones where it could not match a name.

I have over 100 donations in a spreadsheet that I want to upload rather than going to each donor record and uploading all the information.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange! In CiviCRM there is an option in the Contributions menu called "Import Contributions". This allows you to upload contributions from a CSV file. Can you give that a try?

[image]

Comment: There's a 'but' here though.  You'll need to have either the contact's internal id or external id or email address in the input file, in order to match the contribution to the right contact.  Which can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for making it complete Andy Clark :-)